# How to know if a digital camera is doing anti-aliasing filtering?

Tags: digital, anti-aliasing

Is there any way to know if a cellphone digital camera is automatically doing anti-aliasing filtering? Is there any way to have a control over it?

Comment: Why do you care? I very much doubt the AA filter or lack thereof is a significant factor in cellphone camera IQ.

Comment: Please see my last comment. I explained why I care :-)

Comment: And I stand by my comment that an AA filter is not significant in cellphone cameras when compared with the vast amounts of noise reduction all phones apply to their images.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming image manipulation software and not specifically about photography.

Comment: I suspect cell phones do not need AA filters. The pixel density in these cameras is so high that they suffer from diffraction even at the largest aperture opening. The diffraction plays the same role as AA filter.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out if a cell phone is using an anti-aliasing filter is to ask the manufacture.

There is no way to control it. The filter is a physical object, not a program. It sits in front of the sensor.

That being said, I would guess that there is no AA filter because of the small size of the pixels. But that's just a guess. Someone who knows for sure should be answering in the near future.

Comment: But is it possible to get a clue about it from camera specifications? Because I need to know it dynamically( programmatically ), so asking manufacture is not an option.Thanks again.

Comment: I'm guessing you won't get it in the specs because it's too technical for most consumers.

Comment: Well, in theory a cellphone *could* do something like the Pentax K-3 and have a variable AA filter. I don't anyone will ever implement that though!

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: A variable AA filter? I wonder how it works.

Comment: I mean programmatically. I'm developing a software which would need to know if an image is AA filtered.

Comment: @anga: What problem are you trying to solve? It is a lowpass filter, so some frequencies do not get through. No noticeable difference I guess in your case.

Comment: @anga: Your software will not be able to tell whether certain spectrum is being filtered because you do not know the response curve of the sensor cells, and their internal mapping to color values... A little bit of lost sharpness and less aliasing: AA filter on. A bit more sharpness and more aliasing: no AA filter. But you do not have baseline data for that as well to compare the measurements with that.

Comment: I'm doing research on image resolution improvement. My research focuses in cellphone cameras because they are lower resolution and so improvement would be more important. I know that aliasing also contains extra high-frequency information with additional details about the scene. So for my work it would be important. I would like to have more information how much difference a hardware AA filter can make? Thanks again

Comment: @AndyBlankertz - For Pentax, the anti-shake mechanism is on the sensor, they simply move it to emulate strengths of AA or turn it off.

Comment: It's also only on the K3, and really only works at slower shutter speeds.

Comment: @anga: The only way I see is if you could deconvolute with the low-pass filter response and see if the image has higher acuteness than the non-processed one. The image needs to be in focus and you need a heuristic algorithm to say if the image is "better". I don't see any other way to tell if AA is used or not.

Comment: I believe AA filters are usually constructed to overlap 1 pixel. But the cameras most likely use some sort of sharpening, that cancels this type of blur quite well. As I mentioned in another comment, look at diffraction - it is likely to impact resolution of these cameras more than AA filters, if they are used here at all.